# How to have options menu to a user in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing code that has 2 options for the user to type in. For example they type `1` to choose option 1 and `2` for option 2.

Now here's my problem. I get the '1 is not recognized as a command etc. etc.'
Take a look at the code and tell me where I went wrong. Also if you see any other problems feel free to point them out. (I know it says Boot Game?, but it opens tskmngr I was just using that as a placeholder for something)

```
@echo off
title (Program name) PixelShooter Launcher
color 01
cls
:menu
echo PIXELSHOOTER
echo 1 - Start Game
echo 2 - Options

if %name% == 1 goto tskmngr
if %name% == 2 goto "AppData\Roaming\Pixelshooter\config.ini"
pause
:tskmngr
cls
echo Boot Game? (Y/N)
set /p boot
if %boot% == y start tskmngr
cls
if %boot% == n goto menu
if %boot% == y echo (K)
pause
goto menu
:AppData\Roaming\Pixelshooter\config.ini
cls
echo Boot Options?
 set /p boot
 if %boot% == y start AppData\Roaming\Pixelshooter\config.ini
 cls
 if %boot% == n goto menu
 if %boot% == y echo (K)
 pause
 goto menu
```

Comment: Take a look into the [`choice`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php) command.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you currently have doesn't make much sense to me as it is. But here's what I modified the existing code to. But one of you main problems is right above your first pause, your IF is trying to see if there's a non-existant variable set, because you forgot to set said variable, so after that pause the code would flow straight towards the :tskmngr. The SET /P is necessary when waiting for input to be used as a variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 01
:Menu
TITLE PixelShooter Launcher
CLS
ECHO PIXELSHOOTER
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Start Game
ECHO 2 - Options
ECHO 3 - EXIT
SET /P name=Please Make A Selection [1,2,3]:  
IF %name%==1 (GOTO :tskmngr)
IF %name%==2 (GOTO :Options)
IF %name%==3 (GOTO :EOF)
CLS
TITLE INVALID SELECTION
COLOR FC
ECHO "%name%" isn't a valid selection choice, please try a valid selection.
ECHO We'll return to the previous menu.
PAUSE
GOTO :Menu

:tskmngr
TITLE PixelShooter Launcher
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Boot Game? (Y/N)
SET /P boot=Boot Game? [Y/N]:  
IF %boot%==Y (START :tskmngr)
if %boot%==N (GOTO :Menu)
CLS
TITLE INVALID SELECTION
COLOR FC
ECHO "%boot%" isn't a valid selection choice, please try a valid selection.
ECHO We'll return to the previous menu.
PAUSE
GOTO :tskmngr
:Options
TITLE PixelShooter Launcher
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P options=Start Options? [Y/N]:  
IF %options%==Y (START AppData\Roaming\Pixelshooter\config.ini)
IF %options%==N (GOTO :Menu)
CLS
TITLE INVALID SELECTION
COLOR FC
ECHO "%boot%" isn't a valid selection choice, please try a valid selection.
ECHO We'll return to the previous menu.
PAUSE
GOTO :Options`
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the `=` missing at the `set /P` command:

```
set /P boot=
```

or:

```
set /P boot=optional prompt text
```

To ensure that `%boot%` is empty when the user just presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, insert this command before `set /P`:

```
set boot=
```

Otherwise, `%boot%` keeps its previous value.

---

To compare the user input with the predefined options, use `if` like this:

```
if "%boot%"=="1" goto Label
```

The `"` are needed in case the user input is empty.

---

Finally, there is a `choice` command for such one-key options, which sets the `ErrorLevel` to the selected item:

```
choice /C YN /M "Do you want to continue?"
if %ErrorLevel% equ 1 goto Yes_label
if %ErrorLevel% equ 2 goto No_label
goto Fail_label
```

Type `choice /?` in command prompt and read the help text.

Answer (score 0):

This simple modified from you code:

```
@echo off
title (Program name) PixelShooter Launcher
color 01
:menu
cls
echo PIXELSHOOTER
echo( 1 - Start Game
echo( 2 - Options
choice /C 12 /N /M "|Select : "
set ERR=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %ERR%== 1 goto tskmngr
if %ERR%== 2 goto AppData\Roaming\Pixelshooter\config.ini
pause
:tskmngr
cls
choice /C YN /N /M " Boot Game? (Y/N)"
set ERR=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %ERR%== 1 start Taskmgr
if %ERR%== 2 goto menu
if %ERR%== 1 echo (K)
goto menu
:AppData\Roaming\Pixelshooter\config.ini
cls
choice /C YN /N /M " Boot Options? (Y/N)"
set ERR=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %ERR%== 1 start AppData\Roaming\Pixelshooter\config.ini
if %ERR%== 2 goto menu
if %ERR%== 1 echo (K)
goto menu
```